# Game thread won't stop

Tags: java, multithreading

I have tried many ways to fix this, but I can never seem to figure out what would fix this.
My game thread won't stop running when I stop the game!

(Main class)

```
public class Game extends JFrame implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4662621901369762109L;
    public static final Rectangle windowSize = new Rectangle(800, 600);
    public static final int fps = 60;
    private static Game instance;
    private static Thread gameThread;
    public static final PaintCanvas canvas = new PaintCanvas();

    public Game() {
        this.setSize(windowSize.getWidth(), windowSize.getHeight());
        this.setTitle("Test");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.add(canvas);

        Spawner mainSpawner = new Spawner();
        mainSpawner.setPosition(new Point(windowSize.getWidth() / 2 - 30, windowSize.getHeight() / 2 - 30));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        instance = new Game();
        gameThread = new Thread(instance);
        gameThread.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            update();
            try {
                // 1000 divided by fps (for 60 fps, it is 16.666 repeating)
                Thread.sleep(1000 / fps);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void update() {
        for (GameObject g : new ArrayList<GameObject>(GameObjectManager.getGameObjects())) {
            g.update();
        }
        canvas.repaint();
    }

    public static Game getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

I am really bad at threads so please help!

Comment: You also appear to have an infinite loop `while(true)` which only exits if an `InterruptedException` occurs -- if that doesn't happen, you infinite loop.

Comment: The GUI code is irrelevant, and you didnt even show an attempt to stop. Create a boolean to use for your while loop, and set it to false when you want it to stop. Or, you could interrupt the thread from another thread.

Comment: I want it to stop when the player exits the game. I tried changing the while loop to while (gameThread != null), but it still won't work.

Comment: @MCMastery Why would you expect that change to make it work? Nothing there sets `gameThread` to `null` so that would never happen, and even if it did, you'd need to declare `gameThread` as `volatile` for that to work reliably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things:

1. What makes you believe that shutting down the main thread will *interrupt* the game thread? You never call `interrupt()` anywhere so I'm not sure why you expect an `InterruptedException` to occur when the main thread ends. This does not happen.
2. Non-daemon threads will continue running; the JVM will not shut down if there are still non-daemon threads. [Set your new thread to be a daemon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon(boolean)) if this is not the behavior you desire.
3. You may want to consider using a `Timer` or a `ScheduledExecutorService` for your updates instead of creating a new `Thread` as it will generally be easier to manage.

The more common way to terminate a thread, in its most basic form, would be something like:

```
volatile boolean stopMyThread = false;

public void run() {
    while (!stopMyThread) {
    }
}
```

Then when you'd want to stop it:

```
stopMyThread = true;
```

And optionally join on the thread to wait for it to stop.

However, with a [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) or, even better, a [`ScheduledExecutorServices`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()), you can simplify your code a bit.

Comment: Thank you! I set it as Daemon.

Comment: I want it to shut down when the player exits the window.